# How can I set the parent component state based on children component checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Material UI Table component.
In Table component, I want to store the checked prop from  in EnhancedTableHead,
 to my parent component EventManagement.

But I am not sure what is the correct way to do it because I need to extract the event object from , in order to get the checked prop

App.js

```
export default class EventManagement extends Component {
  state = {
    // How to set the below state by refering the table checkbox
    isSelectAllCheckboxSelected: false
  };

  render() {
    return <Table />;
  }
}
```

Demo.js(Table Component)

```
function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
...
  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          {/* How to get the checked prop below and send it to parent component */}
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
          />
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
```

In this case, since the select all checkbox is selected, state isSelectAllCheckboxSelected should be true.
[image]

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hf5z9?file=/demo.js

Comment: You can pass a callback which will update the state of the parent when you take action in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

in your App.js give props function to your Table function:

```
return <Table checkAllButtonTrue={(value)=> {this.setState({isSelectAllCheckboxSelected: value})}}/>;
```

then get the props from the table function:

```
export default function EnhancedTable(props) {
 ...
```

in your handleSelectAllClick function call props function:

```
const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
if (event.target.checked) {
  const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
  props.checkAllButtonTrue(true);
  setSelected(newSelecteds);
  return;
} else {
  props.checkAllButtonTrue(false);
}
setSelected([]);
};
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-91v43?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a callback in EventManagement which would react on every checkbox click and check if number of selected checkboxes is equal to number of checkboxes. Then you can set `isSelectAllCheckboxSelected` according to the result.

In your case you can do it in `handleClick`: `newSelected.length` is the number of selected checkboxes, you could compare it with `rows.length` and send the result using callback.